# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (C++) using qt Creator IDE

Tags: c++, qt, x86-64

I basically got stuck with one of the programs that I wanted to test out because I kept getting this symbol(s) not found error all the time.

My program is very simple, I'm an extreme beginner when it comes to C++ so I'm just trying to learn some inheritance stuff. Below is the structure of the program:

[The object diagram of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr6IW.png)

So it's very simple, I have 2 abstract classes wich is ***Vehicle.h*** and ***MotorVehicle*.h**, ***B*us** and ***Car*** will inherit properties from ***MotorVehicle*.h** and ***Bicyc*le** will be the descendant of ***Vehicle.h*** because it's not a motor vehicle.

There are quite a lot of codes and a number of files so I'll just leave the qt project folder right here if anyone wants to know about the code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1hy9BsfLLwab19wODR2UWhnRmc

Now, for some reason, I kept getting the **Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64** error whenever I want to run the program, I checked the *compile output* of qt Creator and here's what it says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vehicle::MotorVehicle::~MotorVehicle()", referenced from:
  Car::~Car() in main.o
  Bus::~Bus() in main.o
  Car::~Car() in Car.o
  Bus::~Bus() in Bus.o
  "vehicle::Vehicle::~Vehicle()", referenced from:
  Bicycle::~Bicycle() in main.o
  Bicycle::~Bicycle() in Bicycle.o
  "typeinfo for vehicle::MotorVehicle", referenced from:
  typeinfo for Car in Car.o
  typeinfo for Bus in Bus.o
  "typeinfo for vehicle::Vehicle", referenced from:
  typeinfo for Bicycle in Bicycle.o
  "vtable for vehicle::MotorVehicle", referenced from:
  vehicle::MotorVehicle::MotorVehicle(int, int, int, double) in main.o
  vehicle::MotorVehicle::MotorVehicle(int, int, int,    std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double) in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for vehicle::Vehicle", referenced from:
  vehicle::Vehicle::Vehicle(int, int, is std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member    function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Vehicles] Error 1
02:38:06: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Vehicles (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Suffice to say I'm a very confused as I'm very new to C++ and I've tried searching for an answer from other SO discussion threads but I just couldn't find anyhting relevant to mine so it seems (or maybe I just haven't looked hard enough)

Cheers guys, thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your destructor into the Vehicle class, `virtual ~Vehicle()` but you don't provide an implementation for it. If you don't want to free up anything,  you should declare it like this `virtual ~Vehicle() {}`. The same applies to the `MotorVehicle` destructor.

The "symbol(s) not found" error is very misleading. Actually, it's saying that there's a defined symbol, mainly function, which implementation was not found.

Comment: Oh CRAP!!! So that's what it is haha, OMG thank you so much for taking your precious time to look at my code. I'm very very new to this and I don't even know what the destructor really is for so I do have a long way to go down the road.

Cheers mate! Again, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Since you don't use dynamic memory allocation and you don't acquire any resources, you don't really have to deal with destructors. Nevertheless, it is important to know about destructors: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I'll definitely read up on it when I have the time in the weekends probably. Cheers~